# Wordpress: Count number of posts, exclude uncategorized

Tags: wordpress, count, posts

Using this code I can easily get the total number of posts:

```
$post_count = count_user_posts();
echo $post_count;
```

But I need the total to not include posts that are uncategorized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code and see the output:

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1,'category' => '-1',);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
echo count($posts_array);
```

As default, id of `uncategorized` category is 1.